# Unable to get Default Constructor for class in Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, parameterized-unit-test

I have created a unit test project. I get an exception specifying

> Unable to get default constructor for class *****.Tests.Controllers.PersonRegistration

```
namespace *****.Tests.Controllers
{
[TestClass]
public class PersonRegistration
  {
    private ILoggingService _loggingService;
    private IUserManager _userManager;
    public PersonRegistration(IUserManager userManager, ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(_userManager, _loggingService);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
  }
}
```

To eradicate this issue some threads said to add an default constructor without parameters. So I added this also

```
public PersonRegistration()
 {
 }
```

But then I resolved the exception. But I am getting `NULL` values for 
`_userManager` and `_loggingService`

[image: Null Values]

How to resolve that issue. I do not want to generate null values when passing.

**Please help me by suggesting a method to solve this question without using `Moq` or any other mocking frameworks.**

Comment: Hello.. if you look at the answer i posted to your question yesterday you will see that I provided a solution not using Mocks.

Comment: @Wheels73. Thank you. You told me to add a constructor without any params. But it returns `NULL` values for _`userManager` and `_loggingService`

Comment: I'll re-post the bit you need.

Comment: @Wheels73 . Can you please post here as the answer for this question

Comment: [ClassInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    _loggingService = new LoggingService();
    _userManager = new UserManager();
}

Comment: [ClassInitialize] public void SetUp() { _loggingService = new ILoggingService(); _userManager = new IUserManager(); } 

It should be IUserManager and ILoggingService right. Or I am doing a mistake again??

Comment: The IUserManager and ILoggindgService are the interfaces. You need to instance them to the concrete implementation. I dont know what they are as you never posted them. I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @HarshaW You can only call `new` on concrete types. An interface is more of a convention on how classes that implement it should be declared.

Comment: Again, where do you expect instances of these interfaces to magically appear from?

Comment: i still dint get the reason why constructor is not getting called here?
i know we have Classinitialize and testinit, but y cant i use constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As discussed.

Runs once when the test class is initialized.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    _loggingService = new LoggingService();
    _userManager = new UserManager();
}
```

You can also use

```
 [TestInitialize]
 public void Initalize()
 {
      _loggingService = new LoggingService();
       _userManager = new UserManager();
 }
```

This will run before each test is ran in case you need different conditions for each test.

As discussed.  ILoggingService and IUserManager are interfaces. You need to instance them to whatever implementation class "implements" that interface.

If you are unsure.. right click on the interface name and choose "Go To Implementation"

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your Test Class constructor is not public.